# C Language Audio Input/Output

Tags: c, audio, audio-recording

I've already searched for ways to capture/play audio with C Language, but I haven't found anything useful. Is there such a way to do this, or I'll have to use another language like C++, C# or Java?

Comment: I think this question is valid and I have an answer to add. libsoundio is a free, cross platform, open source audio input and output library. It's a low level C interface. http://libsound.io

Comment: I've done with with use  of 
#pragma comment( lib, "winmm.lib" ) in a c console app, just because I wanted to see if can be done.   Though, I'm using VS2019, and they don't really have a pure C compiler, so it might be using C++ behind the scenes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)  is perfectly usable from C.

> PortAudio is a free, cross-platform, open-source, audio I/O library. 
>   It lets you write simple audio programs in 'C' or C++ that will
>   compile and run on many platforms including Windows, Macintosh OS X,
>   and Unix (OSS/ALSA). It is intended to promote the exchange of audio
>   software between developers on different platforms. Many applications
>   use PortAudio for Audio I/O.
>
> PortAudio provides a very simple API for recording and/or playing
>   sound using a simple callback function or a blocking read/write
>   interface. Example programs are included that play sine waves, process
>   audio input (guitar fuzz), record and playback audio, list available
>   audio devices, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no reason to capture - play audio with pure c if it will be used on pc. but its easy with c++ becouse it has ready libraries. or if you want to work with a framework you can try c# or java

Comment: I have already done it with Java. Also, I've found a lot of examples in C++/C#. But I was trying to do it in C, for personal reasons

Comment: infact thats cool! becouse it makes you understand the language more better. I wrote a game with c before (for personal reasons) but i could do it with c# too. i was young that time and in collage. anyway people around me was impressed it :)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. In my opinion, in C# most things are already made, and what you have to do is almost nothing (compared to C). So then I can learn how it works

Comment: yeah. thats right. keep going if you have time. but in business you have to choose easy way.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. Well, I'll try to learn the most I can. Thanks :)